# PostgreSQL 8.3 privileges not updated - wrong usage?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, roles, privileges

I'm having trouble granting privileges to another user in PostgreSQL 8.3. While the GRANT command gives me no error, the privileges do not show up. Do I need to "flush" them?

```
sirprize=# CREATE DATABASE testdb;
CREATE DATABASE
sirprize=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testuser;
GRANT
sirprize=# \c testdb
You are now connected to database "testdb".
testdb=# \z
 Access privileges for database "testdb"
 Schema | Name | Type | Access privileges
--------+------+------+-------------------
(0 rows)

testdb=#
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\z` Shows your table, view, and sequence permissions, for the objects contained within the Database. It does not show permissions on the database itself.  If you create a table or some other object within 'testdb', it will then show up in `\z`'s output.

You can see which Databases exist on your system with `\l` (or `\l+` for a bit more info).

See [section 9.22. of the PostgreSQL 8.3 manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-info.html) for information about how to programatically determine which permissions exist for a user on a given database.

Comment: Thanks! Now I only have to find out why phpPgAdmin does not sohw the database when connecting as testuser, thus preventing even the creation of a new table. But that's going to be another question here ;)