# can't grant user privileges to postgresql database (for a rails app)

Tags: postgresql, psql

I combed through: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDSf and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-roles-and-manage-grant-permissions-in-postgresql-on-a-vps--2 but still couldn't get this to work.

I did this to get postgres to work locally: https://askubuntu.com/questions/42013/problem-installing-and-configuring-postgresql.

```
pavan@myUbuntuLaptop% which psql
/usr/bin/psql
```

this got me in:

```
pavan@myUbuntuLaptop% sudo su - postgres
[sudo] password for pavan: 
postgres@myUbuntuLaptop%
```

So...

```
postgres@myUbuntuLaptop% createuser pavankat
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
postgres@myUbuntuLaptop%
```

this gets all the roles

```
\du
```

that shows pavankat, so the role was made

This works:

```
postgres=# CREATE database lateraldev;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \l
```

Now I try to grant privileges to lateraldev to the user, pavankat:

this doesn't work:

```
GRANT RULE ON lateraldev to pavankat
```

doesn't work:

```
GRANT ALL ON lateraldev TO pavankat;
```

doesn't work:

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON lateraldev TO pavankat;
ERROR:  relation "lateraldev" does not exist
```

this looked like it worked but, \du didn't show anything:

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON DATABASE lateraldev TO pavankat;
GRANT
```

same with this, doesn't do it:

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO pavankat;
GRANT
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO pavankat;
GRANT
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO pavankat;
GRANT
postgres=# \du
```

I used this post: http://imaginaryrobots.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/grant-all-in-postgres/ and copied the shell script into the rails app.

then ran (to make the file executable):

```
pavan@myUbuntuLaptop% chmod 755 give_permissions_script.sh
```

and it doesn't work:

```
postgres@myUbuntuLaptop$ ./give_permissions_script.sh
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE lateraldev TO pavankat;
could not change directory to "/home/pavan/Dropbox/venturelateral"
could not change directory to "/home/pavan/Dropbox/venturelateral"
```

tried this out: http://smokeandumami.com/2009/11/11/grant-permissions-on-all-tables-and-sequences-in-postgresql/
and it seems to have done something, but doesn't work:

```
pavan@myUbuntuLaptop% chmod 755 give_permissions_script2.sh
pavan@myUbuntuLaptop% ./give_permissions_script2.sh
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT ON TABLE public.relname to pavankat;
```

see:

```
postgres=# grant all privileges on database lateraldev to pavan;
GRANT
postgres=# \du
```

This doesn't work either:
connect to the database first:

```
postgres=# psql lateraldev

lateraldev=# GRANT ALL ON DATABASE lateraldev TO pavankat;
GRANT
lateraldev=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 pavan     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 pavankat  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

I'm out of ideas. Help me please?

Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays!

Comment: What's wrong is the expectation that `\du` would report about the granted permissions. It doesn't, unlike commands like `\z` or `\dn+`. See psql's manpage.

Comment: thanks Daniel. I ran both commands and didn't even see the user, pavankat. So I guess none of the commands I ran to give privileges didn't work. Any ideas on how I could get the privileges granted to the user I made?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75696/postgresql-8-3-privileges-not-updated-wrong-usage

Comment: Hey Donovan, that link just says to use \z and \l to check the table permissions and databases.

Comment: show your scripts? and i denote, is the issue in the scripts?

Comment: hey majioa, thanks for responding. I linked to the scripts above. But here they are again: http://imaginaryrobots.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/grant-all-in-postgres/ and http://smokeandumami.com/2009/11/11/grant-permissions-on-all-tables-and-sequences-in-postgresql/

Comment: the scripts I used from the sites didn't work. I give the output and the results in the question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

have you tried:

```
--Change the database ownership
alter database lateraldev owner to pavan;

--and do the same for all tables
psql -tc "select 'alter table ' || tablename || ' owner to pavan;' from pg_tables where schemaname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');" lateraldev | psql -a lateraldev
```

Comment: It worked! But can you break that down for me a bit? want to understand it better...

Answer (score 17):

so after some digging around. Found this on the postgres website. Essentially anything other than a table name needs the type to be explicitly called when granting the permission.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_newly_created_db_name TO my_user_name;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4BDE2E41.5090505@agliodbs.com

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I didn't quite get why GRANT wasn't working as expected and erroring out with relation "<tablename>" does not exist. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Try making the user with `CREATEDB` permission, and then you can create the database with that user. The user will have permission on that database from then on.

```
CREATE USER myuser CREATEDB;
```

I know this isn't a perfect solution, but I hope this works out for you

-Brian

Comment: thanks dude. I'll use this next time when I have to create a new user and assign permissions at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Try sending as a psql command instead.

```
psql -c "GRANT ALL ON lateraldev TO pavankat";
```